# Inserção de imagens no em um frame Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, frames

estou tentando adicionar uma imagem dentro de um `Frame` usando o `Tkinter` através do código abaixo:

```
class Gui():
"""
Implements a GUI for Interactive Dictionary app
"""
def __init__(self, parent):
    self.parent = parent
    self.parent.title('Interactive Dictionary')
    self.logo_frame = Frame(self.parent, bg='yellow')
    self._layout_frames()
    self.set_logo_frame()

def _layout_frames(self):
    self.logo_frame.pack()

def set_logo_frame(self):
    img = Image.open("static/app_image.jpg")
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
    panel = Label(self.logo_frame, image=img)
    panel.grid(row=0, column=0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = Tk()
    app = Gui(window)
    window.mainloop()
```

Minha `window` está em branco. Figura abaixo:
 [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não estou visualizando o erro, imagino que seja algo bem simples. 
O `path` da imagem está correto. O que pode pode estar errado?

Answer (score -1):

Consegui inserir uma image em um Frame com o código abaixo:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()

bottomframe = Frame(root)
bottomframe.pack()

img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("backgrond.jpg"))
panel = Label(frame, image = img)
panel.pack()


brownbutton = Button(bottomframe, text="Brown", fg="brown")
brownbutton.pack()

bluebutton = Button(bottomframe, text="Blue", fg="blue")
bluebutton.pack()

blackbutton = Button(bottomframe, text="Black", fg="black")
blackbutton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Basicamente inserindo uma imagem numa Label e passando o Frame a qual a mesma ficará inserida como o primeiro parâmetro. No meu caso, o **frame** ou o **bottomframe**.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]